# Algorithm for grouping sets with similar attributes

Tags: algorithm, classification

For a secure data access system, I have a collection of Data Requests, each of which has 1 or more attributes a user would like access to.

I'm trying to work out whether a set of "standard extracts" would be feasible, so I would like to group the data requests which have similar sets of attributes into a handful of buckets.

e.g.:

```
request_1: [
  attr_a,
  attr_b,
  attr_c
],
request_2: [
  attr_d,
  attr_e,
  attr_f
],
request_3: [
  attr_b,
  attr_c,
  attr_e
],
request_4: [
  attr_d,
  attr_e,
  attr_f,
  attr_g
]
```

might group as `[request_1, request_3]` and `[request_2, request_4]`. The groups' requests will have overlapping attributes, and there's no requirement that the groups have mutually exclusive sets of attributes.

I cant think of a good algorithm to identify the groups and/or assign request to groups, so I'd love to hear ideas or places to go and read!

Comment: You could use a clustering (e.g., [k-Means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) or probably better [Single Link Clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-linkage_clustering)) based on a set distance (e.g., [Jaccard Index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index)). Clustering tries to maximize intra cluster similarity and  minimize inter cluster similarity which is what you want.

Comment: Thanks @SaiBot, that's really useful!